# how to create a visual studios setup project run other installers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, installation

I have made a Visual Studios CLR cpp project that requires drivers that need to be installed onto the user's PC before it can run. I have made an installer with a visual studios startup project that will download the required installers to the user's PC; however, I cannot find a way to make the VS startup project run the other installers after it is finished downloading. I've tried adding the .exe files into the custom actions section, but the installer will crash. I am running Visual Studios 2017 with the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects extension added on.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found some information here, but not enough to get me anywhere. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup-projects-and-custom-actions/